# How to update google gauge chart using ajax call?

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, google-visualization

I'm not familiar with using ajax especially with gauge chart so I don't know where the problem might be. In the gaugechart.php, I can't make an array for gauge chart so this is how I just do it, I dunno if that's where the problem might be.

```
 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined
        at drawChart (index3.php:16)
        at callback (index3.php:12)
        at loader.js:156
        at loader.js:120
```

My code to be able to update gauge chart real time:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf8" />
  <title>Gauge</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      callback: function() {

        drawChart();
        setInterval(drawChart, 10000);

        function drawChart() {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'gaugechart.php',
            type: 'get',
            success: function(json) {
              var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
              var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('gauge_div'));
              chart.draw(data, {
                width: 500,
                height: 200,
                minorTicks: 5
              });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(errorThrown + ': ' + textStatus);
            }
          });
        }
      },
      packages: ['gauge']
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gauge_div" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mt-3"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Code for gaugechart.php for the dynamic data of gauge chart.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'adminpanel');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_waterquality ORDER BY id DESC';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // assuming ONE result

$temperature = $row["temperature"];
$pH = $row["pH"];
$DO = $row["DO"];
$turbidity = $row["Turbidity"];

echo <<<EOT
[
["Label", "Value"],
["Temperature", $temperature],
["pH", $pH ],
["DO", $DO ],
["Turbidity", $turbidity ]
]
EOT
?>
```

Comment: you need to include JQuery script before running it

Answer (score 1):

updated code, would be you need to include JQuery in your html

```html
...
<title>Gauge</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
```

Comment: Oh the error is gone now, but I didn't know that it will not display anything?

Comment: @CorbinJones probably there is an error in your PHP, if you inspect elements in browser and find out any error or open a new question based on your finding